# i have to get a column userid from a row in a list

Tags: java, list, jsp, servlets

I have to basically delete the row by clicking a button,so the variable id is getting the row when delete button is clicked.
Variable id is getting the row no that i select and using for loop i am trying to get the row no that the user select when clicking button and then extracting userid from the row and then using a prepared statement deleting it from the database.

```
                  // int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("user"));
                  // System.out.println("row"+" "+id);

                   List<registerValues> RegList = (ArrayList<registerValues>)session.getAttribute("regList");
                   int sizeOfList=RegList.size();
                   System.out.println("Size of List :"+sizeOfList);
                   List<registerValues> list = new ArrayList<registerValues>();


                   for(int i = 0 ; i<=sizeOfList ; i++) {

                      System.out.println(RegList.get(id-1).toString());


                   }
                    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("delete from registration where userid=?");
                    ps.setInt(1,id);

                   int i=ps.executeUpdate();  
                   if(i>0)
                    {
                      RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp");  
                       rd.include(request,response);
                             }
                   else
                     {
                          RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp");  



                          rd.include(request,response);
                      }

            }
public class registerValues {
public String name;
public String city;
public String gender;
public String username;
public String password;
public String email;
public String contact_no;
public int userid;

public int getUserid() {
    return userid;
}
public void setUserid(int userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getContact_no() {
    return contact_no;
}
public void setContact_no(String contact_no) {
    this.contact_no = contact_no;
}
```

}

this is where my values are selected from database
public static List Registervalues()
         {

```
         Connection conn = null;
         PreparedStatement pst = null;
         ResultSet rs = null;
         values.registerValues registerobject=null;
         List<registerValues> list = new ArrayList<registerValues>();
         try {
            conn = getDbConnection();
             pst = conn.prepareStatement("Select name,city,gender,username,password,email,contact_no,userid from registration");

             rs = pst.executeQuery();


             while(rs!=null&&rs.next()) {

                registerobject= new registerValues();
                registerobject.setUserid(rs.getInt("userid"));
                registerobject.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                registerobject.setCity(rs.getString("city"));
                registerobject.setGender(rs.getString("gender"));
                registerobject.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                registerobject.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                registerobject.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                registerobject.setContact_no(rs.getString("contact_no"));

                list.add(registerobject);


                System.out.println("REGISTRATION values present");

             }
             conn.close();
```

}

Comment: what exactly is your problem ? Why do you have a loop to print out elements from your list? How exactly is the value of id obtained?

Comment: well i don't understand what it is exactly you want to do

Comment: in for loop i am getting this instead of values of 
   list.values.registerValues@79a70c39
values.registerValues@79a70c39
values.registerValues@79a70c39
values.registerValues@79a70c39
values.registerValues@79a70c39

Comment: You need to explain better what you want to achieve... it seems very unclear. Your title says "i have to get a column userid from a row in a list".. you want to get the id of a column before deleting it? Is that what you mean?

Comment: what does the loop have to do with anything?

Comment: i want to delete a row from a table by using buttons and it should be deleted from the database. To delete i must know the row no of table that is provided by the id .I am able to do till this point but now to delete a row from databasei t should be like this( delete from tablename where userid=?) .So now I want userid to delete the row.Can you help me with this@Jonathan Laliberte

Comment: ok, so where are you having the problem?

Comment: values.registerValues@79a70c39
values.registerValues@79a70c39
values.registerValues@79a70c39
values.registerValues@79a70c39
values.registerValues@79a70c39                                                                                I am getting this when loop is running instead of values

Comment: post the code for your `registerValues` class

Comment: @Jonathan Laliberte I have posted the registerValues class

Comment: check my answer, you can get the userid like that... (providing you have set the userid elsewhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the values of the RegList like that:

```
 System.out.println(RegList.get(id-1).toString()); //wrong
```

RegList is a list of `registerValues` so you need to use the getters for getting a value:

if you want to get the userid:

```
 System.out.println(RegList.getUserid());
```

Let me know if that helps.